# Select & Assign Specific Row of a ListBox to a Variable As String

Tags: vb.net

I have tried to find an answer to this but have had no luck. I am using VB.NET and VisualStudio 2019

I have a listbox (lboxsectionnames)that has several different section names listed (as shown in the screenshot). I am trying to specify a specific row, and assign that row to a variable as text.

For this instance I am trying to get the first row text, however, I would like to be able to specify row # in future and get text as well.

```
 Dim firstSectionName
 lboxSectionNames.GetItemText(0)
 firstSectionName = lboxSectionNames.SelectedIndex.ToString
```

[ListBox Text Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B277v.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ListBox.Items is an ObjectCollection and can be accessed with your index like this

```
lboxSectionNames.Items(0).ToString()
```

or using SelectedIndex like this:

```
lboxSectionNames.Items(lboxSectionNames.SelectedIndex).ToString()
```

although you could also do the above like this:

```
lboxSectionNames.SelectedItem.ToString()
```